# MySQL, query with "NOT IN ( SELECT ... )" very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Here is the query runs over 10 minutes.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE name NOT IN(
SELECT a.name
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.code = b.code 
INNER JOIN tableC c ON c.number = b.number 
INNER JOIN tableD d ON d.code = b.code 
INNER JOIN tableE e ON e.content= d.content)
```

Is there alternative query runs faster or any solutions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try not exists

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA t1
WHERE not exists (
SELECT 1
from tableB b
INNER JOIN tableC c ON c.number = b.number 
INNER JOIN tableD d ON d.code = b.code 
INNER JOIN tableE e ON e.content= d.content
where t1.code = b.code

)
```

Comment: Coz there is no column "name" in table B, so I only use t1.code = b.code, and it works well. Thank you very much

Comment: anyway you want but that would be the logic

Answer (score 3):

Your query should work fine provided proper indexes are in place. You can maybe try using left join.

```
select a.*
from tableA a
left join (
    select distinct a.name
    from tableA a
    inner join tableB b on a.code = b.code
    inner join tableC c on c.number = b.number
    inner join tableD d on d.code = b.code
    inner join tableE e on e.content = d.content
    ) b on a.name = b.name
where b.name is null;
```

The performance will mostly depend on indexes. 
For performance, I'd recommend following indexes:

```
create index idx_tablea_code_name    on tableA(code, name);
create index idx_tableb_code_number  on tableB(code, number);
create index idx_tablec_number       on tableC(number);
create index idx_tabled_code_content on tableD(code, content);
create index idx_tablee_content      on tableE(content);
```

Comment: not in relplaced with left join  that should do it without creating index or no? just asking because i think the query will be executed for every record but this way the query will be executed only one time

Comment: @Charif - No. your query will not execute like that (the one you are talking about is called correlated query). Some time left joins are better than NOT IN.

Comment: I do not have a column "name" in table B, so I used "a. code = b. code" instead of  "a.name = b.name" at the end, and got an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'b.code in 'on clause'. But still thank you for your help.